# android update navController from button

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I started a new app with the default android bottom navigation menu.
In the basic main fragment I added the buttons for all the fragments (I want to show them in the bottom navigation but also in the main fragment.)

Then I added this in `HomeFragment` to handle on button press to switch fragments:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);

    homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });

    Button btnConnect = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new ConnectFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    });


    Button btnOptions = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnOptions);
    btnOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new OptionsFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    });

    return root;
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Now I am able to switch between the fragments, but the navigation controller isn't being updated, and when I switch from those buttons to another fragment, in the navigation controller at the bottom, the icons are not updated, and t looks like I am still on the home fragment.

this is the code inside `MainActivity` for the navigation controller:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_options, R.id.navigation_contact)
            .build();

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```

So what do I need to do, in order to make the navigation controller update the icons wen I switch fragments from the customized buttons and not from the navigation controller menu?

**EDIT:**
here is an image to clarify:
on the left is the main activity, on the middle is how it looks like when I switch fragment by pressing on the button "CONNECT" from the main activity, and on the right is  how it looks like if I press the "connect" button from the menu.
I want that the menu will be updated, even when I press the "CONNECT" button from the main activity, and not only from the menu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
yourBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_contact);
```

When you click on your Button

Comment: the navigation is initiated on the MainActivity class. how can I find it on thefragment?

Comment: Okey. For that you can use listener :)

Comment: can you please add a bit more details? it wont be a overhead just for that?

Comment: No it won't be overhead. It's straight forward. You can make your own Listener and implement method in Activity.

Comment: More Simpler way would be Having your button onClick Events in MainActivity itself. 
You can do it by using `android:onClick` property in your xml.

Comment: It's the first time I'm trying to create an app usng fragments. until now I did it just with activities, therefore I would appreciate if u can provide an example